# Which output and input should I use on this function generator?

Tags: amplifier

I'm planning to generate a signal and amplify it. I couldn't find the manuals but I have the detailed pics.
The function generator:
[image: http://www.inlec.com/images/products/zoom/1355241216-31311000.jpg]

And [the amplifier is here](http://kleinanzeigen.ebay.de/anzeigen/s-anzeige/zoffmusic-za200-professional-mosfet-amplifier-verstaerker-endstufe/233165664-172-5421)

My question is:
1) The function generator has 2 outputs (ttl/cmos and 50ohm), which one should I use?
2) The amplifier has 2 inputs, one is balanced sym and one is not balanced, which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the function generator you must use the 50 Ohm output.  Use the asym input on the amplifier (1/4 inch phone plug.)  You will need a cable with a BNC connector on one end and a 1/4 inch phone plug on the other.  Connect the shield on the BNC (outer connection) to the sleeve on the phone plug.

Comment: there exists a cable with BNC connector on one end which goes into sym input. cant i use this? whats the difference?

Comment: Does the cable you have belong to one of the devices?  If it doesn't belong to the amplifier, then it may be connected wrong internally.  Since the output of the signal generator is asymmetric, I would go with the asymmetric input.

Comment: sym input is connected to the amplifier the other end is bnc. how do u know that output of func. gen. is asymmetric?

Comment: BNC is always asymmetric.

Comment: i dont know why but one side is  bnc othey is symetric and is plugged into sym in amplifier. so is that totally wrong?

Comment: So you actually have a cable that is made for use with both the generator and the amplifier? Or do you have just some cable with BNC and a connector like the one on your amplifier?  Have you checked how the cable is wired?  It wouldn't be totally wrong to connect the cable that way, just really odd.

Comment: the cable i have is such that one end is bnc and the other end is already plugged to sym input of the amplifier. after i read ur comments i hesitate to connect the bnc end to the func. gen. output. i dont wanna damage anything.

Comment: Check the wiring of the cable.  Make sure that the center of the BNC does not connect to the ground of the other end (marked with an inverted T on the amplifier.)  As long as both sides of the BNC are connected to the symmectric connections of the amp you should be OK.

Comment: On the BNC-XLR cable, I'd expect the center contact of the BNC to connect to pin 3 of the XLR, with the shield (outer) fo the BNC connected to pins 1 and 2 of the XLR.  It would also work with the signal to pin 2, and pin 3 grounded.

Comment: @PeterBennett: Standard XLR wiring is: Pin 1 = shield, Pin 2 = Hot (+) phase, pin 3 = Cold (-) phase.  Connect pin 3 to pin 1 if connecting an unbalanced source to an XLR input (pin 2 is hot).  For an XLR output connecting to an unbalanced destination, either leave pin 3 open (active balanced output) or connect pin 3 to pin 1 with a 100R resistor (if you don't know).

Answer (score 0):

The TTL / CMOS output on a function generator is *usually* a pulse output used to provide sync to other test equipment.  The 50 Ohm output is the main output and will provide whatever signal shape you have selected.

Both outputs are unbalanced (what you are calling "asymmetric").  That is: they have a ground connection and a hot connection.

The link to your amplifier is not valid anymore, so I can't comment.  But if it has an XLR microphone-type connector, the amp is expecting a balanced signal.  You can feed your unbalanced signal into that input by connecting pin 3 of the connector to pin 1.  Your signal source connects with ground to pin 1 and hot to pin 2.

If this is an actual microphone input, you will need to attenuate the signal from the function generator.  A 40 dB pad is usually pretty close - this is a "L" type network where the series resistor is 100k and the shunt resistor is 1k.  That is: insert a 100k resistor in series with the signal from the generator and add a 1k shunt resistor across the input pins of the amp.

You mention that you have an unbalanced input.  If this is a line-level input, simply connect the function generator to that input.  Shield from the BNC connector goes to the sleeve of the connector, the center pin on the BNC connector goes to the center pin of the connector.

If this is also a mic-level input, pad appropriately.  Again, 40 dB is a good value to start with.